# Ubuntu 18.04 login loop and can't change tty's language (overlapping problem)

Tags: 18.04, tty

I have Ubuntu 18.04 after installing flatpak I got the login loop problem, but my main problem is with tty's default language which seted to Arabic, so i can't login to apply any solution I've found for the looping issue.

Any suggestions for how to change the tty's language, or fixing the login loop problem ?!

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] By following the instructions in this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

After mounting my root partition, I used "sudo apt-get purge flatpak" to  Uninstall flatpack, and it works with me.